# comma separated values in oracle function body

Tags: oracle, plsql, tokenize

I've got following oracle function but it does not work and errors out.  I used [Ask Tom's](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425) way to convert comma separated values to be used in `select * from table1 where col1 in <>`

declared in package header:

```
TYPE myTableType IS table of varchar2 (255);
```

Part of package body:

```
l_string        long default iv_value_with_comma_separated|| ',';
l_data          myTableType := myTableType();
n               NUMBER;

begin
  begin
LOOP
    EXIT when l_string is null;
    n := instr( l_string, ',' );
     l_data.extend;
     l_data(l_data.count) := ltrim( rtrim( substr( l_string, 1, n-1 ) ) );
     l_string := substr( l_string, n+1 );
END LOOP;
end;

OPEN my_cursor FOR
  select * from table_a where column_a in (select * from table (l_data));
CLOSE my_cursor
END;
```

above fails but it works fine when I remove

```
select * from table (l_data)
```

Can someone please tell me what I might be doing wrong here??

Comment: What is the error that you get .Can you post it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't give us the actual error, which makes it harder for us to diagnose your problem.  However, it is worth a punt: `ORA-00902: invalid datatype`

You haven't implemented Tom's solution exactly as he gave it.  Specifically, he created  `myTableType` as a SQL Type whereas you have declared it in the package specification.  This is not a trivial detail: we cannot use PL/SQL types in SQL statements.  Hence the exception.

So, remove the declration of MyTableType from the package and create it in SQL....

```
create or replace type mytabletype as table of varchar2(255);
/
```

You SELECT statement should now work.  If it doesn't please edit your question to give us the exact error message.

**edit**

> "I want everything to be inside the
>   package. What do I have to change to
>   accomplish that?"

Here is a kluge.  As you can see, PKG1 declares the PL/SQL type in the spec:

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg1 as
  2      TYPE myTableType IS table of varchar2 (255);
  3      function split (p_string  in    long )
  4          return          myTableType ;
  5      function get_resultset (p_tab in myTableType)
  6          return sys_refcursor;
  7      function get_resultset_for_str (p_string  in    long)
  8          return sys_refcursor;
  9  end pkg1;
 10  /

Package created.

SQL>
```

In the package body you will recognise SPLIT() as Tom Kyte's solution.  GET_RESULTSET() loops through a passed collection and assembles a dynamic SQL statement.   GET_RESULTSET_FOR_STR() is a helper funnction which calls both the other functions.

```
SQL> create or replace package body pkg1 as
  2      function split (p_string   in     long )
  3      return          myTableType
  4      is
  5              l_string        long default p_string || ',';
  6              l_data          myTableType := myTableType();
  7              n               number;
  8          begin
  9            loop
 10                exit when l_string is null;
 11                n := instr( l_string, ',' );
 12               l_data.extend;
 13               l_data(l_data.count) :=
 14                       ltrim( rtrim( substr( l_string, 1, n-1 ) ) );
 15               l_string := substr( l_string, n+1 );
 16          end loop;
 17          return l_data;
 18      end split;
 19
 20      function get_resultset (p_tab in myTableType)
 21          return sys_refcursor
 22      is
 23          return_value sys_refcursor;
 24          stmt varchar2(32767);
 25          i pls_integer := 1;
 26      begin
 27          stmt := 'select '''||p_tab(1)||''' from dual';
 28          while i < p_tab.count()
 29          loop
 30              i := i+1;
 31              stmt := stmt||' union all select '''||p_tab(i)||''' from dual';
 32          end loop;
 33          open return_value for stmt;
 34          return return_value;
 35      end get_resultset;
 36
 37      function get_resultset_for_str (p_string  in    long)
 38          return sys_refcursor
 39      is
 40          l_tab myTableType;
 41          return_value sys_refcursor;
 42      begin
 43          l_tab := split(p_string);
 44          return_value :=  get_resultset (l_tab);
 45          return return_value;
 46      end get_resultset_for_str;
 47
 48  end pkg1;
 49  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

Here is it working in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec :rc := pkg1.get_resultset_for_str('ABC,DEF,XYZ')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

'AB
---
ABC
DEF
XYZ

SQL>
```

Comment: I tried removing MyTableType declaration from the package and kept it outside in SQL and that works ok.  But I want everything to be inside the package.  What do I have to change to accomplish that?

Comment: The query can only work with "SQL" types, not "PL/SQL" types.